# what's sweet-ass beach in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

In  the last sentence of following paragraph, he said "took sweet-ass beach vacation". Please give me a short explanation about sweet-ass . thank  you.

“Elliot” was a successful man, an executive at a successful company. He was well liked by his coworkers and neighbors. He could be charming and disarmingly funny. He was a husband and a father and a friend and took sweet-ass beach vacations.

Answer (score 1):

"Sweet ass X" is a slightly vulgar, slang expression meaning "really cool."

By itself, "sweet" is slang for "cool." Additionally, adding "-ass" to certain adjectives is a colloquial way of emphasizing them. Hence, "sweet-ass X" or "sweet ass X."

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked it up in [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Sweetass)? Basically, “sweet-ass” is a slang term for “awesome”. See also [“sweet”](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sweet). Adding “ass” to an adjective is a slang way to intensify it- so “sweet-ass” is even better than “sweet” by itself.

“Beach” describes where Elliot goes on vacation - “sweet-ass” describes the beach vacations. Elliot takes awesome vacations to the beach.

Comment: I agree with the answer, but Urban Dictionary should _never_ be considered an authoritative or reliable reference. Encouraging English language learners to rely on it is probably not a good thing, since a very large percentage of its contents is complete garbage.

Comment: @TypeIA that's fair. I guess Wiktionary also has good slang definitions (if "standard" dictionaries don't), and is probably more reliable. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ass